# Bind enum value to label in data template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, enums

```
<Label Content="{Binding ActivityName}" Foreground="Black"></Label>
<Label Content="{Binding ActivityType}" Foreground="Black"></Label>
```

When I bind a list of `Activity`'s to this `DataTemplate`, I can see the `ActivityName` (a `String` property) displayed in the `Label` fine. The `ActivityType`, however, is an `enum`, and this doesn't bind to the `Label` at all. I'm assuming I need to call some sort of `toString()` on the enum but I don't have a clue how to do it in XAML.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695976/wpf-binding-enum-type-to-textbox

Comment: Thanks, looks like that might be the answer. A lot of work for something so simple though.

Comment: Yeah, indeed I agree! Had the same problem few months ago gl ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out

```
<Label Content="{Binding ActivityType,StringFormat={}{0}}" />
```

Comment: Your solution worked fine. The problem was with another part of my code. Thanks again.